# Non-Linear Regression with Keras loss not decreasing: Outlier and/or data format problem?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, outliers, non-linear-regression, loss

I'm owning a data table and two of its columns produce a plot that looks like this. Please note, that the Y-Axis is in log.

[Don't mind the random Kanji. That's already fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xOhC.png)

I thought it might be a good idea, to display this relation via a non-linear regression produced by Machine Learning using TF and Keras. The code looks like this:

```py
def createModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
    model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

    return model

model1 = createModel()
model1.compile(SGD (lr=0.0001),loss='mse')
print(model1.summary())

Taisha_Learn=model1.fit(Heisei_Learn["竣工年月"],Heisei_Learn["平成27年まで詰めた堆砂容量_Percent"],batch_size=50, epochs=1000, validation_split=(0.08), verbose=2)

predictions = model1.predict(Heisei_Learn["竣工年月"], verbose=1)
plt.plot(Heisei_Learn["竣工年月"],predictions)
# plt.legend([ 'Predictated Y'])
plt.show()
```

The model performs horrible. The loss is almost not diminishing. Subsequently, this is the prediction.

[Absolutely horrible prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHFzF.png)

I already played around with a different optimizers (Adam, RMSprop), Learning Rates and Batch-Sizes, with no positive effect.
I pondered whether it might be a data problem due to outliers. I just filtered it for NaNs in the respective column.

```py
Heisei = pd.read_excel("日本ダム/平成２７.xlsx")
Heisei_Learn=Heisei.dropna(subset=['平成27年まで詰めた堆砂容量_Percent'])
```

I really tried many changes, but normally the loss looks sth like this:

[Nightmarish Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hAVL.png)

There must be a better way to get a real non-linear regression out of the data. Is there sth about them I must change? Again, plz take a look at the graph posted in the original question. It rly freaks me out --.--...

Is there anybody decent out there to help out someone foolish like me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a regression setting, the activation of your output layer should be *linear*, and definitely not softmax (which is normaly used only for classification); change the last layer of your model to

```py
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

or simply to

```py
model.add(Dense(1))
```

since the default activation (i.e. if you don't specify anything) is linear ([docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)).

Having done this, start experimenting with learning rate `LR` values around 0.001...

Comment: Hi desertnaut! 

Thanks for your swift reply. I already tried for it, but without any different result. The loss rapidly changes towards something around 26000 where it stays. Previously it was 30000 with almost no change. Both values are not desirable.

Also I was a li'l confused by the naming: Will the "Linear" activation be able to produce a "nonlinear" regression?

Comment: @JDS yes, linear in fact means 'no activation' (`a(x)=x` - see the linked docs); the fact than one layer has a linear output does not affect the fact that the output of the *model* is non-linear...

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Nevertheless, the function still remains very, uhm, linear: A quite horizontal line...

Comment: I updated the original post a li'l, however the problem remains unfortunately, whatever I did so far

Answer (score 0):

1. NN are not performing amazying on regressions. Consider converting your problem to a classification problem (if possible)
2. Relu is better be replaced with LeakyReLU
3. The biggest problem is probably loss, where 'mse' cause a huge loss because of the outliers. Try 'mae'. But be ready for average results because of the first point.